# 24bit or better ADC at 10V with at least 100ksps?

Tags: adc

I have a signal from 0 to 10V dc.  I need to 24bit or better ADC that signal at 100ksps or greater.  I can't find ADCs that will do that, they either read at lower voltages or not as fast.  I have contemplated using a normal ADC with a MUX http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9907 and tune each section to a seperate voltage range, then scan till its in range and ADC the signal then.  I didn't want to have to manipulate the data that much.  Or use a 4 2.5V ADCs using relative ADC line references and scan 0 - 2.5, 2.5 - 5, 5 - 7.5 , and 7.5 - 10.  Then add them together in the end to get the total ADC.  I would like to do this on one chip or know a "good" way to do it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you just use a voltage divider?  What kind of ADC are you looking for (MCU peripheral, ADC IC, analog DAQ...)

Comment: @Nick - You should consider making that an answer.

Comment: What is the required resolution?  Using voltage divider resulting in a 0 - 5V range with a 16 bit ADC gives you 5/65536 = 76.3 uV per bit.  Is that sufficient?  Resolution is a key spec. for an ADC.

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with the hardware, I strongly recommend using a discrete ADC. That way, if you have problems, you can just stick a logic analyzer on the ADC interconnects, and see exactly what is going on.

Comment: This is for a micro.  I want to read the data in digitally.  I will use any method that gets me the requirements.  Didn't know if there was a simpler way, or an "approved" method.  I am not unfamiliar with hardware, just unfamiliar with "approved" and standards when using it.

Comment: Sorry it took so long for me to comment.  I couldn't be on yesterday evening.

Comment: 24bit is not easy to design, we're talking 0.06ppm for the last bit! Poor layout may cause something like 6-8 LSB to be useless.

Comment: Getting real data out of all 24-bits is extremely difficult.  Professional Pro Tools $1000 24-bit audio converters, for instance, have a dynamic range of 113 dB, which is really only 19-bit.  The other bits are just representing noise.

Comment: @endolith, isn't [1 LSB out of a 24-bit value just 72 dB?](http://www.google.com/search?hl=&q=10*log%281%2F%282\*\*24%29%29)

Comment: No, it's 20*log10.  10*log10 is for powers, not voltages.  The easier rule of thumb is "6 dB per bit".  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range#Audio  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're feeding this to a MCU or similar, I would use a basic resistor voltage divider to cut the 0-10 V to 0-5 V or similar.  I might pad the range a little to avoid saturation near the top-end due to tolerances, and maybe add some clamping diodes depending on the application.  Many MCUs are capable of 100 ksps nowadays, some DSPICs can even do 1 Msps.

Random anecdote: One of my first PCBs I had made as an intern was a big resistor divider array for our test engineers who had to connect automotive analog stuff (0 V to BATT; 9 to 16 volts) to their 0-5 V DAQs.

#### Additions

24-bit @ 100 ksps...not doable with any MCU (I know of).  You can use [oversampling and decimation](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc8003.pdf) to hit 24 bits, but you take an effective 4x sample rate hit per bit of increased resolution.

I don't know about your application, but I might try to cheat and go with a 96 ksps rate.  96 kHz audio is fairly common nowadays, so it might be easier/cheaper to get an ADC for that.

*Possible parts available @ DK:*

- Cirrus Logic CS5343-CZZ - [IC ADC AUD 98DB 108KHZ 10-TSSOP](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=598-1189-ND) (Cirrus has a few others, CS5346-CQZ, CS53L21-CNZ)
- Analog Devices AD1974YSTZ-ND - [IC ADC 4CH W/ON-CHIP PLL 48LQFP](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=AD1974YSTZ-ND)
- Texas Inst. PCM1808PWR - [IC ADC 24BIT STER **96KHZ** 14-TSSOP](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=296-26307-1-ND)

In any case, regardless of the IC, halving the range per bit with a voltage divider is a very clean and basic method, almost assuredly lower noise than passing through any demultiplexer.

Comment: I saw your comment about 1MSps dsPICs and thought it seemed high so I looked it up. Turns out they go up to 10bit x 4MSps (dsPIC33FJ64GS608). Holy smokes.

Answer (score 3):

Robert's MAX197 has a multiplexer, which you maybe don't need. You also don't mention word width. Here are a few single channel ADCs from Maxim:

> [MAX1156](http://www.maxim-ic.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/3738): 14-bit, 135ksps
>   [MAX1177](http://www.maxim-ic.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/4040): 16-bit, 135ksps
>   [MAX1187](http://www.maxim-ic.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/3647): 16-bit, 135ksps
>   [MAX1157](http://www.maxim-ic.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/3640): 14-bit, 135ksps
>   [MAX1132](http://www.maxim-ic.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/3068): 16-bit, 200ksps
>   [MAX1142](http://www.maxim-ic.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/2533): 14-bit, 200ksps

Comment: Analog devices also has a pretty nice lineup.  Here is their product selector: http://www.analog.com/en/analog-to-digital-converters/products/index.html  You should be able to use a resistor divider to get your signal range down to 5V.

Comment: Spec'ing Maxim parts is a newbie mistake.  The datasheet looks good, the samples work well, and then you go to production and find there's a six month lead time and no second sources.

Answer (score 0):

Try a [MAX197](http://www.maxim-ic.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/1042).  There are a couple of other versions that are similar, but this is a starting point.